# Counting the median, mean and standard deviation for 3 dynamic tables and adding them to a file

Tags: c, mean, median, standard-deviation

I wrote a program that reads a file and creates 3 dynamic arrays into which it reads X, Y and RHO values. I would like to create functions or procedures that calculate the mean, median and standard deviation for each of these values ​​and save these statistics to a file. I tried to write it but it doesn't work.
Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MagicData
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double rho;
};

struct MagicDataArray
{
    size_t reserved;
    size_t count;
    struct MagicData *data;
};

void MagicDataArrayAppend(struct MagicDataArray *arr, struct MagicData* data)
{
     if (arr->count >= arr->reserved) arr->data = realloc(arr->data, sizeof(struct MagicData) * (arr->count * 3 / 2));
     arr->data[arr->count++] = *data;
}

struct MagicDataArray MagicDataArrayCreate(size_t reserved) {
     struct MagicDataArray result = {
           reserved,
           0,
           malloc(sizeof(struct MagicData) * reserved)
     };
     return result;
}

struct MagicDataArray MagicDataArrayReadF(FILE *f)
{
     struct MagicDataArray result = MagicDataArrayCreate(10);
     struct MagicData tmp;

     fscanf(f, "LP X Y RHO"); // ignore header
     while(fscanf(f, "%*d. %lf %lf %lf", &tmp.x, &tmp.y, &tmp.rho) == 3)
     {
          MagicDataArrayAppend(&result, &tmp);
     }

     return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("grades.txt", "r");

    struct MagicDataArray r = MagicDataArrayReadF(f);
    printf("%zd\n", r.count);

    for (size_t i=0; i < r.count; ++i)
    printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", r.data[i].x, r.data[i].y, r.data[i].rho);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's a link to my file: https://easyupload.io/8swlt1

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work

Comment: In this snippet: `...) arr->data = realloc...`, shouldn't you verify that `realloc...` was successful before using `arr->data`?  And _it doesn't work_ is not a good description of your problem.  Use whatever code you have linked (which by the way does not work.) to produce a [mcve], and post it instead.

Comment: Certainly when the `if` is taken in `if (arr->count >= arr->reserved) arr->data = realloc(arr->data, sizeof(struct MagicData) * (arr->count * 3 / 2));`, 1) `arr->reserved` should be updated. 2) hopefully  `arr->count != 0`.

Comment: I hope that now the link will work

Comment: On my opinion the code was very understandable and clear. I do not see benefit in updating the code. However, it could more clearly be stated what actually goes wrong under which circumstance.
When i compile (using cl under windows as well as gcc under wsl) and start this providing the test data, the code seemingly works. Is there maybe some other problem and you wrongly suspected the code above?